# How to Tell That This is a Hyperbola?

Tags: real-analysis

{${(x_1,x_2) \in \Re^2 : x_1x_2 = 1, x_1 >0}$}

I'm trying to prove that the set is closed but I have trouble visualizing these sets. My book says this "is the branch of the hyperbola that lies in the first quadrant."
How can I tell this? Is it from $x_1x_2 =1$

Comment: Since $x_1$ can't be $0$, you get $x_2 = \frac{1}{x_1}$.

Comment: Visualling it isn't really that important but, yes, this is $x_2 = \frac 1{x_1}$ which should be a familiar graph to you.

Comment: [**Wikipedia**]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) has a pretty good description of the more general problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***hint***
$$x_1x_2=1$$
you can write it like 
$$ \underbrace {(x_1+x_2)^2-(x_1-x_2)^2}_{\color{blue}{=4x_1x_2}}=4$$
Substitute $x=x_1+x_2$ and $y=x_1-x_2$:
$$x^2-y^2=  4$$
$$(\frac x2)^2-(\frac y2)^2=1$$
Clearly an hyperbola
$$x'^2-y'^2= 1 $$
Since $x_1>0$ we have $x_2>0$ and the curve is in the first quadrant

Answer (score 1):

The sign of the discriminant $B^2-4AC$ of the general conic $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ lets you determine the type of conic. In this case, it equals $1\gt0$, so the equation is that of a hyperbola.